# Tables inside table in lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am trying to access the element of a table which is inside a table.

```
MainTable={Table1={},Table2={},Table3={}}

Table1.is="Bool"
Table1.Name="Bit1".
```

similar parameters for Table2 and Table3

If I access either `Maintable.Table1[is]` or `Maintable[Table1[is]]`, it is returning null.

How do I get the value of `is` or `Name`?

How I can use pairs in this regard?

Answer (score 3):

```
MainTable.Table1.is="Bool"
MainTable.Table1.Name="Bit1".
```

In this case

```
print(MainTable.Table1.is) // Bool
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use either of these methods:

```
MainTable.Table1.is
MainTable.Table1["is"]
MainTable["Table1"]["is"]
```

to get the same result.

Here is a working example: http://eval.in/16665

Comment: Thanks for the input.It helped me a lot.Can I access Table1,Maintable by assigning the names to variables.Example: local test=Maintable,local test1=Table1.Now if I do Print(test.test1["is"]) I am getting error as wrong index.

Comment: Because `Table1` in itself doesn't exist. The `test1` will be set to `nil`.